# error in as.data.frame.default when knitting a r markdown file

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

**When I run the following code chunk in r markdown, I get the expected outcome. However, when I tried knitting the file into html, an error message shows up. The data are from an excel file and I read the data using read.csv function.**

Error message: error in as.data.frame.default (data, optional=True): can not coerce class "function" to a data.frame calls: ...terms.formula -> as.data.frame.default execution halted

```
total_steps <- aggregate(steps ~ date, data , sum)
total_steps
```

Comment: Can you show the `dput(data)`

Comment: It seems like maybe `data` isn't defined (at least by that name) in your Rmd document.

Comment: as gregor mentioned the error is that data is not defined that why R defaults to the utils::data function hence the error message

Comment: When a Markdown is knitted, this is done in a different environment than the one you're using, hence the comments above : you must define data in the Markdown document

Comment: This is a good example of why naming a dataset `data` (or any of the common R functions) can lead to confusing results. In your original environment, if you had named your data `mydata` instead of `data`, then the error instead would have been something like `object 'mydata' not found`.